# UI Automation debug messages with iPhone 5.0 simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios-ui-automation

With 5.0 simulator every tap and scroll results in debug message in output log. Example:

```
Debug
11/14/11 4:00:10 PM GMT+02:00
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().navigationBar().rightButton().tap()
```

With 4.3 simulator everything's OK. How to turn off debug messages spam in 5.0 simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defaults write com.apple.Instruments3 UIAVerboseLogging -int 4096`

to reset:

`defaults delete com.apple.Instruments3 UIAVerboseLogging`

You will need to restart Instruments after either change to see an effect.